# How do I optimize this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the layouts in an Android app by flattening view hierarchies. Here's a particularly difficult one!

[image: A very inefficient layout]

This layout has a main LinearLayout to hold the top and bottom rows (which are horizontal sub-LinearLayouts themselves). Each of the four items in the middle is a vertical RelativeLayout (to accommodate the ImageView and textView) spread out using layout_weights. Each row containing two items is ALSO a horizontal LinearLayout.

Needless to say, this layout is atrociously inefficient, leading to a lot of "Choreographer has skipped frames" messages when it is being drawn. I'd like to eliminate these nested Layouts, but AFAIK RelativeLayout is not helpful in equally spacing out the items in a row horizontally, and the two rows in the centre vertically. Also, I considered replacing the ImageView and TextView with a compound drawable, but I don't know how I can control the drawable's size.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**:
Here's a rough description of the Layout.

```
<!-- The top bar -->
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="80dip"
android:background="@drawable/some_image">
    ...
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Central Layout -->
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- First Row -->
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">


        <!-- Item 1 -->
        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

         <!-- ImageView and TextView here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Item 2 -->
        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

         <!-- ImageView and TextView here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- End of first row layout -->

    <!-- Second Row -->
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">


        <!-- Item 3 -->
        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

         <!-- ImageView and TextView here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Item 4 -->
        <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

         <!-- ImageView and TextView here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
<!-- End of second row layout -->

</LinearLayout>
<!-- End of central layout -->

<!-- Bottom bar -->    
<LinearLayout...>
....
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be helpful to post the current xml file of what you have, instead of explaining

Comment: Believe me, you don't want to see it! I guess I could add a "pseudo layout", though.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks a lot like the one shown in demo given by the Android team here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

I am by no means super savvy with GridLayout (lots of trial and error before I get it working) but looking at what you have it should do the trick (esp if you would move all the buttons at the bottom to the top, and had them as an ActionBar).

Getting rid of the layout_weights will improve everything lots as every time those are used they are measure again and again.

Answer (score -1):

The most optimum way of doing this would be to write your own custom `ViewGroup`. It's quite straightforward if you understand how android does its laying out.

See these slides by Romain Guy:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B_VKZCqEnHblNDdiY2UxODgtYWNhNS00MmU4LWE4NDMtZjQ1OWI5MDMxZTVh&sort=name&layout=list&num=50.